# get value from jtable

Tags: java, jtable

I have a jtable and I want the user to fill its cells then i get what he wrote!
the problem is when i try getValueAt(row index,col index ) the programe give me null , and i am sure that the cell i choose has a value .
 following show how i create the table

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number of rows");
    int row = Integer.parseInt(s);
    Vector v = new Vector();
    v.add("URL");
    DefaultTableModel Dm = new DefaultTableModel(v, row);
    jTable1.setModel(Dm);
```

Comment: How are you creating the table? Are you using the default table model? Care to post some code ?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you use the default model. You can obtain the selected cell and display the content by writing something like this :

```
int i = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
int j = jTable1.getSelectedColumn();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, j));
```

Or if you want , use `getRowCount()` and `getColumnCount()` to get other cells value. But all that explanation depends on one question:

- how did you create/fill the table - as **@nc3b** said ?